# JavaScript How to download image using bookmarklet or UserScripts?

Tags: javascript, image, download, bookmarklet, userscripts

I have an image that I need to download from a website automatically.
The link looks like this:

```
http://example.com/image.php?NewsID=7
```

How can I do it automatically using bookmarklet or userscripts (JavaScript)?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768771/how-to-search-for-a-specific-url-in-a-target-pages-code-and-start-a-download